# How to call when each of a group pays and shares expenses?

Tags: terminology

Me and my friend are flatmates. I spend $100 for bills, he spends $60 for shared groceries. Every once in a while we balance out our expenses; in this case my friend gives me $20, or makes a $40 expense for something else we need.

How to call this small economic system, where shared expenses are made by more than one person from their own wallet, and everyone exchanges money to clear any debts?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It looks like your question might be a [single-word-request]. Should this be the case, please provide a sample sentence, e.g. "When I poke a jelly and it makes a wavy motion, it is ____.", to which the answer might be "wobble".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a specific term for your process of reconciling periodically. But the general idea that you all pay equal amounts in the long run is commonly called *pooling expenses* or *sharing expenses*.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be **financial solidarity**.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solidarity):

> unity (as of a group or class) that produces or is based on community of interests, objectives, and standards

A similar term can be found in [**solidary obligations** (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidary_obligations).